# connect to an appared device, not visible

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I am currently developping an Androïd application, and I would like to know which appared devices are accessible for a connection.
I have access to the appared devices, and to every device visible nearby.
I tried to compare the two lists in order to get these accessible devices.
The problem is that most devices can be set visible for only two minutes, while appared devices are available for connection without having to be visible.
How can I get to know which appared devices are available for connection ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean **paired** devices. in this case you simply call the method getBondedDevices from the BTadapter and receive a set of BluetoothDevice object. like this:

```
BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = btAdapter.getBondedDevices();
for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
    System.out.println("device name: "+device.getName() + " device address: " + device.getAddress());
}
```